# ViewPager with twice as many fragments as it should have

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Can someone help me understand why the following bit of code works on one Fragment but not on another, making me end up with twice as many inner fragments as I should have and making the TabLayout and ViewPager get out of sync:

Fragment:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_companies_ranking, container, false);

    pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    tabLayout = (TabLayout)mainView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("1");
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("3"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    viewPager = (ViewPager)mainView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    viewPager.requestFocus();

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    return mainView;
}
```

Xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".activities.companies.MyFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:background="@color/color_white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

PagerAdapter:

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>(2);

    public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);

        fragments.clear();
        fragments.add(OneFragment.newInstance());
        fragments.add(TwoFragment.newInstance());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }
}
```

Update:

Ok, found it, I had some leftover code from the MainActivity where the fragment is being instanced and there I was adding the very same Fragment that contains the ViewPager.

Not quite sure why it was behaving like this, as both ViewPagers were both on different places and had different names, but still, that's what was causing the odd situation.

Does anyone knows the answer to why exactly this was happening when both instances were technically different and shouldn't be affecting each other?

Or am I missing something?

Either way, I thank everyone for the ideas which made me go over and re-look everything regarding all the used Fragments, without that I'd probably be lost in this confusion loop for a few more hours at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the documentation of [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)). Your ViewPager doesn't make twice the pages. onCreateView is called once for each instance returned by  getItem

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is something going on with the way you initialize your fragments in the constructor of the adapter and the way you use FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Try using a FragmentPagerAdapter so your fragments aren't being destroyed in the background, also try setting up your tabLayout with the

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewpager(viewPager);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it, I had some leftover code from the MainActivity where the fragment is being instanced and there I was adding the very same Fragment that contains the ViewPager.

Not quite sure *why* it was behaving like this, as both ViewPagers were both on different places and had different names, but still, that's what was causing the odd situation.

I thank everyone for the ideas which made me go over and re-look everything regarding all the used Fragments, without that I'd probably be lost in this confusion loop for a few more hours at best.